# OpenFlow - what controller should I use

Tags: networking, openflow, opendaylight

I used the Floodlight for some openflow testing but I am not totally convinced by this and I saw that OpenDaylight is sustained by Linux Foundation and some of the major industry companies.

Can someone point some strong features that OpenDaylight have and FloodLight don't ? And if someone worked with OpenDaylight could point me to some good tutorials ?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked out the Wiki? There is a lot of topics there. It is still getting sorted out and what not so you may need to use the search engine to find specifics more times then not.

We have some images that are pre-built OpenStack builds. The latest is from a couple of weeks ago for the upcoming OpenStack IceHouse release.

[ODL and Icehouse Integration](http://www.siliconloons.com/opendaylight-integration-with-openstack-has-merged-into-icehouse/)

All in all it is still rough around the edges and has a ton of development happening still.

There are some basic mininet examples using OpenFlow and the OVSDB plugin here:

[OpenFlow and Mininet](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller%3aInstallation)

OVSDB ODL plugin:

[ODL and OVSDB Plugin with Mininet](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OVSDB_Integration%3aMininet_OVSDB_Tutorial)

For API related apps, Fred Hsu's blog while a bit dated now has some great examples:

[OpenDaylight Api App usage](http://fredhsu.wordpress.com/?s=opendaylight)

If you have any other specific interests the IRC channel is a good place to interact at irc.freenode.net #opendaylight or ping us in #opendaylight-ovsdb

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This is the best one from the opensource available
*http://sdnhub.org/releases/floodlight-plus-openflow13-support/*
*http://www.projectfloodlight.org/projects/*
Hope this will help